# Date arithmetic formating in Bash

Tags: macos, command-line, bash

I have a script that creates previous week's folders with the week number in the name. Here's how I'm getting the value of the current week number and assigning the previous week's number.

```
WEEKNBR=$(date +"%V")
PREVWK=$((WEEKNBR-1))
```

The value of `WEEKNBR` is in a two digit form eg. "Week05" but the `PREVWK` would be "WEEK4".
How would  go about subtracting 1 from `WEEKNBR` and have the result be preceded by `0` when applicable?

Comment: Are you intending to stop using this script before the end of the year?  What happens when PREVWK ends up as 0?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `date` to do the arithmetic for you. With BSD date:

```
$ /bin/date +%V
03
$ /bin/date -v-1w +%V
02
```

From `man date`:

```
-v   Adjust (i.e., take the current date and display the result of the
     adjustment; not actually set the date) the second, minute, hour,
     month day, week day, month or year according to val.  If val is
     preceded with a plus or minus sign, the date is adjusted forwards
     or backwards according to the remaining string, otherwise the
     relevant part of the date is set.  The date can be adjusted as
     many times as required using these flags.  Flags are processed in
     the order given.
```

In case you have installed and are using GNU date:

```
$ date -d '-1week' +%V
02
$ date -d '-1 week' +%V
02
$ date -d 'now - 1 week' +%V
02
$ date -d 'last week' +%V
02
```

Comment: Best answer, otherwise, what result do you want in week 1 of the year?

Comment: for the week one case i  have .  `if [[ $PREVWK == 0 ]] . 
 then . 
 PREVWK=52 . 
 YEAR=$((YEAR-1)) . 
 # echo 'prevwk:' $PREVWK . 
 # echo 'prevyear:' $YEAR . 
fi`

Answer (score 2):

A "one-liner" (OK, two-liner) is

```
WEEKNBR=$(date +"%V")
PREVWK=$(printf %02d $((WEEKNBR-1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are after here is a way to check if `$PREVWK` is 2 digits long or not, in which case you respectively either prepend a `0` to the beginning of the existing number or not.

**Implementation:**

```
WEEKNBR=$(date +"%V")
PREVWK=$((WEEKNBR-1))

if [[ $(echo -n ${PREVWK} | wc -c) -lt 2 ]] ; then
    PREVWK="0${PREVWK}"
fi
```

It looks at the number of digits in the variable (be sure it is always a number) and decides if it is made up of less than 2 digits. If so, it prepends `0`, else it leaves the number alone. This way, weeks like `23` will stay as `23` instead of `023`, and so on.

Let me know if that works for you or if you are looking for another/different way to achieve it. You could also check if the number as a whole is less than 10, meaning a leading `0` needs to be added.

Comment: Terminal is for terminal app, not general command line questions. Thanks for the excellent edit and more importantly good answer that explains things.

Answer (score 1):

A one liner approach **that won't break when the new year rolls around** and that always gives the correct week number for seven days before the current moment:

```
weeknbr="$(date +%V)"
prevwk="$(date -j -v -7d +%V)"
```

Note that I'm using lower case names because these are not (or should not be) environment variables; see:

- [Are there naming conventions for variables in shell scripts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/42847/135943)

---

P.S.: I see that muru has written an essentially identical answer, but I had this tab open for some hours before getting back to it and neglected to refresh.